# Process TCP PSH

Tags: c, linux, networking, tcp, netfilter

I modified the IP headers of TCP packets and directly sending them out in the netfilter NF_INET_LOCAL_OUT hook. The TCP connections can be successfully established. Unfortunately, the data packets with the PSH flag set can not be well processed by the peer. However, if I let the data packets with PSH go through the default linux stack and the other packets go through my module, all TCP packets will go though well. May I know what happens to the data packets with PSH? How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: It's really unclear what you try to do and what failure you see. Do you modify existing packets or change them? Do you set the PSH flag, clear it, or what?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Actually, I only modified IP headers but did not modify TCP headers and payloads. I did not set the PSH flag. I observe that the PSH flag was set in fault if the packets are data packets in Linux. Thanks.

Comment: I am working on a CentOS 6.2 machine with Kernel 2.6.32.27. Thanks.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. The PSH flag is normal for data packets, and normally doesn't have much influence.

Comment: Yes, actually, that is my question. If I modify the packet headers with PSH flag, the peer cannot process the packets well. However, if I only modify the other packets, e.g, with SYN and ACK, and let the packets go into the default linux stack, the peer can process them well and responds correctly.

Comment: If I modified the packets with PSH, I print the information. It seems that the local host is keeping send the same data packets before the connection is torn down, which shows that the peer does not process the packets correctly.

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question, to explain yourself, instead of doing so in comments. And I still don't understand - one time you say that you only modify the IP headers (not TCP), and then that you set the PSH flag, which is on the TCP header.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Actually, as I mentioned, I did not set the PSH flag. I just modified the IP headers. My questions is why the packets with the PSH set cannot correctly processed by the peer if I modify the IP headers of the packets. However, the other packets without PSH can go through well.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading the [following article](http://packetlife.net/blog/2011/mar/2/tcp-flags-psh-and-urg/) with regards to PSH flags.

There is a likelihood that the recipient of packets with PSH flags set, is trying to buffer the packets, as opposed to just PuSHing them through, and this is what is causing errors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems that it cannot solve my problem. I only modified the IP headers of all TCP packets, but did not modify the TCP headers. I wonder why the peer stack only ignores the packets with the PSH flag. It can correctly process the other packets, e.g., TCP connections can be correctly established.

Comment: Initially, PSH was created to tell machines: "hey this is important above all, you need to send this through." It is a legacy flag in the sense that, when it was created, networks were slower, and it was a mechanism in the interprocess to say: "hey this is crucial! send it through" Where the recipient would PuSH it through. The issues surrounding this became: 1) Speeds increased and 2) Security hazards. As speeds increased, and security issues become more prevalent, most companies saw no need when programming, to enable this flag.

Comment: Not to forget mentioning, because of the security risks, most providers along the route (from Point A through Point B) were filtering/stripping this flag, so it became useless

Comment: Thanks for the point. Actually, the issue is that the receiver can indeed see the flag set in the packets. I try to remove the flag when sending the packets. All packets will be correctly delivered to the TCP layer. Unfortunately, the problem is raised that the data packets will be sent out before the handshaking procedure is finished. It is obvious the the communication still fails.